# Can I legally allow my dog to pee on someone's fence?

Tags: property, scotland, pets

I live in Scotland and my dog likes to have a wee at 3D objects. Particularly he likes peeing at wooden fences and bushes of my neighbours.
Now they're not very nice, they always complain no matter what.

Am I breaking the law by letting the dog have a wee there or is it considered to be public area because it's the side of the street?

Comment: As opposed to having a wee at 2D objects?? Somebody help us if your dog manages to wee on a [tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract) ;D

Comment: @Keeleon, you are laughing, but that's what my dog does when you take her for a walk. Anything sticking out must be marked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you are not breaking any laws. There is a law about *fouling* but that's about defecation.

[Dog Fouling (Scotland) Act 2003](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/asp/2003/12/contents)

Comment: Hey down voters, tell me what's the problem.

Comment: I think this is correct (and indeed depending on the plants it may be good for them !) - but if I were the neighbours, I might be inclined to trespass you and your dog.  (To @jqning - people are like that on this Stack Exchange.  It kinda sucks, but don't take it personally)

Comment: You are legally right, but slightly technically wrong.  Urine is excrement, in that it has been taken into the body and excreted.  Feces is not excrement as it has not really entered the body (the digestive canal is not really inside the body).  The law (or the wiki page) specifies "defecates".

Comment: @Dave I changed excrement to defecation

Comment: The Wikipedia link was for repealled E&W-only legislation so I've replaced it with the current Scottish Act