# Can an prospective employer ask for information about your previous salary and base their offer on that?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, salary

Can a public-sector employer ask for information about a prospective employee's previous salary? Can they base their offer to the employee on that information? Can the offer be below the advertised salary range?

Comment: OK thank you. Does the range of salary advertised not matter in this case?

Comment: TheDude: Note again that this question boils down to, "Is this OK?"  Here's a single answer that may apply to all your questions: **Nothing is illegal unless it violates a law.**  Now: Asking whether a law exists is generally a bad question because it's very hard to prove that a law *doesn't* exist in whatever jurisdiction you might be referencing.

Comment: @Thedude I shouldn't have said "good question" but "better" question. I agree with feetwet's critique of the pattern in your questions.

Comment: I apologize folks. I'll keep them more general from now. What about the one with the dog and the fence? https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8034/can-my-dog-pee-on-someones-fence

Comment: You ask whether they can ask for the information. They almost certainly can. But the next question is, can you refuse it? You can certainly try: "I'm sorry, they made me sign a non-disclosure agreement on that, but you could write to them and ask".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you haven't given any jurisdiction or any industry, I'll just answer with the common law answer: yes.

An employer is at liberty to ask for any information as long as they are not prevented from doing so by law.

They are entitled to use any information at their disposal to calculate a salary offer.

Employment contracts almost always include an "entire agreement" clause, meaning that the advertised salary means precisely nothing.

Comment: Going a bit further, the advert is not the offer. Hence the offeror's ability to offer less.

Comment: Obviously the prospective employee is also allowed to ask for more money. Or to not tell the new employer what the old salary is.